# Scala parallel file download

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, future

Imagine I have a list of URLs and a function that downloads the corresponding file:

```
val urls = List(url1, url2, url3)
def fetch(url: String): File = ...
```

I wonder if there a better way to download those files in parallel than this:

```
val futureFiles: Future[List[File]] = Future {
  urls.par.map(fetch)
}
futureFiles.map(files => ...)
```

One problem I see is that now I can only access the files once they've all been downloaded. How to achieve something as concise and elegant and be able to act on each downloaded file as we go?

Comment: An aside, you can't wrap some computation in a `Future` and expect it to be async/non-blocking (see note [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAsync#How-to-create-a-Future[Result])). How I'd love if it was that simple... xD

Comment: You'd better be off using [Play WS library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS), or some other really async HTTP library.

Comment: @insane-e given a properly configured execution context, the download still will happen in parallel and that is all he asked for, or am I wrong? You are right that you can't make blocking code non-blocking by wrapping it in a future, but that's exactly the situation we currently have with most SQL drivers. And yes, +1 for Play WS :)

Comment: @fxlae Yes, it would do it in parallel. The end result is the same. :) Only difference is (I think) that the threads running these HTTP requests will be **blocked** (waiting, doing nothing useful) until the response is returned.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
urls.par.map(fetch).map(file => ...)
```

This way both the fetching and the "handling" of the fetched files are done in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

> ...a better way to download those files in parallel...

It depends on what you mean exactly by "download those files in parallel". Imagine you want to download three files (based on your example: `val urls = List(url1, url2, url3)`). This could mean two different things:

- Just moving the downloads away from your current thread, but not caring whether the downloads themselves are performed in parallel or sequentially (so possibly url1 is fetched before url2, followed by url3), **or**
- Moving the downloads away from your current thread, and also performing the downloads themselves in parallel (all urls are fetched at the same time).

If the first option is what you want, then the answer provided by Tzach Zohar is a good approach. The parallel collection will put your urls in partitions and assign one thread to each partition. If you have 3 elements, your downloads most probably will be done sequentially because there is only 1 partition. If your `List` of urls is larger, then you'll also get more threads, but the urls within each partition will still be fetched sequentially.

If you instead want to download all files at the same time (option 2), then you need a bit more control over parallelism. Your `Future` approach is not that wrong, but instead of putting the whole download process into one single `Future`, you'll need one `Future` per url.

Your code could look like this:

```
val futureFiles: List[Future[File]] = urls.map(u => Future(fetch(u))) // note: no par
```

Note that you now get a `List[Future[File]]`, not a `Future[List[File]]` as before. Subsequently, you can map over every `Future` individually instead having to wait for one single `Future` to complete (as before).

```
futureFiles.map(_.map(file => ...))
```

Optionally, you can afterwards transform the resulting `List[Future[T]]` to a `Future[List[T]]` by using `Future.sequence`.

You have to make sure that you use a properly configured `ExecutionContext`, otherwise, parts of your downloads still might be performed sequentially. Apart from that, it's a good idea to replace your blocking IO with something really async (see the comment from insan-e).